# How to add new items to the persistent multiple-choice AlertDialog?

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android, android-alertdialog

Basically what I'm trying to do is to imitate the google+ app, where the user can circle other people. The circles are presented in a listview with a checkbox, and the top row of the list is something like "add new circle", and the user can create new circles by clicking on it. I know there are many tutorials on AlertDialog, but I haven't found any tutorials for this task. Can anyone explain how to implement this? Thank you!

Comment: Well what have you tried so far and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: @XaverKapeller Well, I tried to follow the tutorial on android developers. But the example is one where all the rows in the AlertDialog are checkboxes. I just want the first row to contain no checkbox, just saying something like "create new circle", and when the user click on it, they can add a new row to the list with a checkbox. I actually have no idea how to continue.

Comment: The tutorial on android developers is a good place to start. If you need a custom layout than you have to create a custom `AlertDialog`. I assume you meant [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout), in the chapter "Creating a Custom Layout" you will find every thing you need to know.